# Flexbox grid: two equal length rows, top row split into two columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a layout like the following image using css flexbox.

But I'm not much familiar with flexbox anyone can help me to make this?

[image]

Here is what I'm trying:

```css
.row.flex {
    display: flex;
 }

 .row [class=^"col-"] {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row flex">
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
  
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
  
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
  
 </div>
</div>
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option 1

Set the flex container to `wrap`.

Make each flex item take 50% of the space. Adjust for margins with `calc`.

The third item, which is forced to wrap, gets `flex-grow: 1`, so it consumes remaining space.

```css
.row.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
 }

 .row [class^="col-"] {
    flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 10px);
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
 }
 
 .row [class^="col-"]:last-child {
     flex-grow: 1;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row flex">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"></div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"></div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12"></div>
</div>
```

---

### Option 2

Set the flex container to `wrap`.

Give each flex item just enough width to allow only two per row.

Give each item the ability to consume remaining space.

```css
.row.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
 }

 .row [class^="col-"] {
    flex: 1 0 35%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row flex">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"></div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"></div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12"></div>
</div>
```